# How can i fix this flickering surface in pygame (python)?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to build a simple game in which you dodge the squares falling from the top by moving your player. I was thinking about adding shooting to destroy the falling squares and other things, but i got stuck here.
I tried using Chat GPT but it couldn't help me.
When i run the code, a square gets stuck in the top left corner of the window and flickers while all the others fall as they should.

```
import pygame, sys
import random

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

#Setting up the screen dimensions
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1920
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1080
FPS = 60



#Creating the game window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Dodge')

#Setting up the clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Player, self).__init__()

        self.surf = pygame.image.load('graphics\player.png')
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

        self.x = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2
        self.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 10 * 9
        
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

        self.max_speed = 15
        
        self.velX = 0
        self.velY = 0

        self.acceleration = 0.7
        self.friction = 0.9

    def update(self):

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            if self.velX > -self.max_speed:
                self.velX -= self.acceleration
                
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            if self.velX < self.max_speed:
                self.velX += self.acceleration
                
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            if self.velY > -self.max_speed:
                self.velY -= self.acceleration
                
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            if self.velY < self.max_speed:
                self.velY += self.acceleration
                
        
        self.x += self.velX
        self.y += self.velY
        
        self.velX *= self.friction
        self.velY *= self.friction
        
        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

        if self.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH
            
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
            
        if self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREEN_HEIGHT
            

class Obstacle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):

        super(Obstacle, self).__init__()

        OBSTACLE_WIDTH = 64
        OBSTACLE_HEIGHT = 64
        
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((OBSTACLE_WIDTH, OBSTACLE_HEIGHT))
        self.surf.fill('white')
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

        self.x = random.randint(5, SCREEN_WIDTH - OBSTACLE_WIDTH - 5)
        self.y = - OBSTACLE_WIDTH

        self.velY = random.randint(15, 20)

    def update(self):

        self.y += self.velY
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
        if self.rect.top > SCREEN_WIDTH + 5:
            self.kill()


ADD_OBSTACLE = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(ADD_OBSTACLE, 250)

#Player instance
player = Player()

#Obstacle group
obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()



#Game loop
run = True
while run:

    #Event handler
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        #Closing the game
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False

        elif event.type == ADD_OBSTACLE:

            new_obstacle = Obstacle()
            obstacles.add(new_obstacle)
 

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
    for obs in obstacles:
        screen.blit(obs.surf, obs.rect)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, obstacles):

        player.kill()
        run = False

    player.update()
    obstacles.update()

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

# Quit the game
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I tried changing the update method for the Obstacle class, the y and x values but nothing worked, if i lower the FPS value, the flickering gets slower but still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you create an `Obstacle`, you don't initialise its `rect` coordinates until after it's drawn. The default `rect` position is `(0,0)` so you see your obstacle for a single frame in the top left corner. Next game loop, the screen is cleared and obstacle is drawn in its *correct* position, causing a flickering effect.

You can solve this by setting the `rect` position in the `Obstacle` contructor, e.g. adding `self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)` after you've set the coordinates.

You can also move your drawing code to after `obstacles.update()` is called.

You can also take advantage of [`pygame.Group.draw(*surface*)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) by changing `Obstacle.surf` to `Obstacle.image`.

A typical game loop looks something like *Event Handling → Game State Update → Draw Sprites → Update Display*, which would have hidden the initialisation problem.

Comment: thank you, i added more things like a menu and a restart option, and by doing that i reordered the code and using your advice the problem was fixed!